# angular js watch parent scope

Tags: angularjs, watch

I have lengthy form in my site. session time out expired before form submission finish.

so we thought to provide some auto save option. for this I have done this auto save by watch each child scope in form and call function to save it in DB as below

```
$scope.$watch('Nomination.selectedOrgiManager', debounceSaveUpdates);
    $scope.$watch('Nomination.nomineeInfo.isTeamNomination', debounceSaveUpdates);
    $scope.$watch('Nomination.nomineeInfo.teamName', debounceSaveUpdates);
    $scope.$watch('Nomination.selectedNominees.length', debounceSaveUpdates);
```

but i thought that this watches will dump memory until nomination form closed. is it?
so I thought to watch parent scope as below

```
$scope.$watch('Nomination', debounceSaveUpdates,true);
```

but here, the problem is what are the object changes, DB function call. so each time we access DB in this option. so i think it will also take memory to access DB whenever child object changed.

Is there any better solution to achieve this? or does added watches for each child scope is best way or add watch for parent scope is best way.

Please provide solution for this.

Comment: you can try `ng-change` and save in `localstorage`

Comment: Thanks. but how to send those localstorage data to DB. I need to store form data before session expired.

Comment: localstorage is saved in user's browser. You don't need DB or session for it.